# Multi select no showing chosen values from model, but single select does ruby on rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-chosen

I am using ruby on rails, but i am having trouble displaying the selected values from the database in the multi select form. The single select works fine but the multi select is displaying blank values, i have checked the values coming from the controller and they are correct but it doesn't display the values!! I am using the jquery plugin from the multi select but i don't think this is the problem.

```
<!-- chosen select for course categories -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="medium-5  column with_chosen"> 
    <%= f.collection_select :categories,
    Category.all ,:id,:name,
    { include_blank: false},
    { :multiple=>true, class: 'chosen-select medium',  :data => { :placeholder => ' ' }}
    %>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- change partner for course -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="medium-5  column"> 
    <%= f.collection_select :partner,
      Partner.all, :id,:name ,
    { include_blank: false },
    { class: 'chosen-select', :multiple=>false, :data => { :placeholder => ' Brand Partner' }}
    %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any advice would be great?

Comment: Please give me your issue demo Links...

Comment: @PiyushMarvaniya not sure what you mean by issue demo links

Answer (score 0):

May be work for you.

```
<!-- chosen select for course categories -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="medium-5  column with_chosen"> 
    <%= f.collection_select :categories,
    { :selected=>Category.all.collect{|c| c.id}},
    { include_blank: false},
    { :multiple=>true, class: 'chosen-select medium',  :data => { :placeholder => ' ' }}
    %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="medium-5  column with_chosen">
  <%@course_categories=[]%>        
      <% @course.categories.each do |t| %>
      <% @course_categories << t.id.to_s %>
      <% end %>
    <%= f.collection_select( :categories,
    Category.all ,:id,:name,
    { include_blank: true, selected: @course_categories },
    { :multiple=>true, class: 'chosen-select medium',  :data => { :placeholder => ' ' }})
    %>

  </div>
</div>
```

So what i did is i passed the multi select an arrays of id's that were converted to sting, it then matches up the ids and displays the selected values from the database!!